# Django show "It worked" page instead of my project when I start it docker

Tags: django, docker

I'm trying to create docker container with my application, that works good on local machine and production server. But when I create docker container with my project I see only "It worked" page instead of my project!

```
FROM python:2.7
MAINTAINER Name name <mail@gmail.com>
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE lms.settings
RUN ls -la /
RUN mkdir /lms/
WORKDIR /lms/
RUN pip install six Django==1.5.12 numpy python-dateutil Pillow django-colorful gunicorn south djangorestframework djangorestframework-jsonp simplejson psutil
ADD . /lms/
RUN (cd /lms/ && python manage.py syncdb --noinput)
RUN (cd /lms/ && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput)
RUN ls -la /lms/
RUN cd /lms/
CMD gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=lms.settings lms.wsgi --pythonpath '/lms/' --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Your Run command executes the cd and exits,  Either change your last command with a cd,  or better use earlier  WORKDIR

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your Dockerfile like this

```
FROM python:2.7
MAINTAINER Name name <mail@gmail.com>
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE lms.settings
RUN ls -la /
RUN mkdir /lms
WORKDIR /lms
RUN pip install six Django==1.5.12 numpy python-dateutil Pillow django-colorful gunicorn south djangorestframework djangorestframework-jsonp simplejson psutil
ADD . /lms
RUN python manage.py syncdb --noinput
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
RUN ls -la 
CMD gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=lms.settings lms.wsgi --pythonpath '/lms/' --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`
```

See the doc for WORKDIR 
https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#workdir

and this "best practices"

https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/

When you `RUN cd /lms` it executes the cd and exits, so the next command is not in /lms and also, do not put a / at the end of your directory when you specify the WORKDIR, as you had twice WORDKIR, your default directory was /lms/lms I guess